# DB Design - Foreign key to multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, relational-database

I have the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Username] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    [Domain] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    [IsAdministrator] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'false',
    [IsGroup] BIT NULL DEFAULT 'false', 
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Role]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Name] NVARCHAR(500) NOT NULL, 
    [Description] NVARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL, 
    [ResourceType] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
)
```

A user can be assigned one or more roles for a particular resource

For example,
Say there are 2 types of resources (`Workspace` and `Process`)

There will be a table for each resource type, and the schema for each resource will be different (hence I can't use a generic resource table)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Workspace]
(
    [WorkspaceId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, 
    [WorkspaceName] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR(500) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [UC_WorkspaceName] UNIQUE([WorkspaceName]),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Workspace] PRIMARY KEY([WorkspaceId])
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Process]
(
    [ProcessId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL , 
    [ProcessName] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_BusinessProcessId] PRIMARY KEY ([ProcessId]), 
)
```

but irrespective of the resource type, the primary key will always be a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`.

Each user can have one or more roles assigned for a particular ResourceId and ResourceType

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserRole]
(
    [UserId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [ResourceType] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [ResourceId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_User_Role] PRIMARY KEY (ResourceId, UserId, RoleId, ResourceType),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [User]([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_RoleId] FOREIGN KEY ([RoleId]) REFERENCES [Role]([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

But with this design I can't set `UserRole.ResourceId` as a foreign key since it could either be `WorkspaceId` from the `Workspace` table or `ProcessId` from `Process` table.

This becomes a problem during resource deletion as I have to remove obsolete entries manually.

I know I could have 2 columns in `UserRole` called `WorkspaceId` and `ProcessId`, setting `NULL` based on resource type, but in my case the number of resource types will be quite large.

My question Is,

Is there any other way where I don't have to add a column for each new resource type or should I just go with the current design (without a foreign key)?

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Google sql/database subtyping/inheritance/polymorphism & its antipatterns many/multiple fks [sic] to many/multiple tables. Just googling your title should hit answers about this. Always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags.

Answer (score 0):

I would combine workspace and process into a single table, and have them link to a ResourceType table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Username] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    [Domain] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    [IsAdministrator] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'false',
    [IsGroup] BIT NULL DEFAULT 'false', 
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ResourceType]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Description] NVARCHAR(100)
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Role]
(
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Name] NVARCHAR(500) NOT NULL, 
    [Description] NVARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL, 
    [ResourceType_id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Resource]
(
    [ResourceId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL, 
    [ResourceName] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR(500) NULL,
    [ResourceType_id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [UC_ResourceName] UNIQUE([ResourceName]),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Resource] PRIMARY KEY([ResourceId])
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserRole]
(
    [UserId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [RoleId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [ResourceType] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [ResourceId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_User_Role] PRIMARY KEY (ResourceId, UserId, RoleId, ResourceType),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [User]([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_RoleId] FOREIGN KEY ([RoleId]) REFERENCES [Role]([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_ResourceId] FOREIGN KEY ([ResourceId]) REFERENCES [Resource]([ResourceId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: The schema for resource types will vary significantly, that's why I couldn't go for a generic `Resource` table. I'm sorry I didn't mention that properly in my question